C++ EOF Help Using Ctrl + Z and While Loop
I'm struggling a bit to understand how to set this up properly.
Just a bit of background. I'm new to programming and I've only been using C++ for 3 weeks now.
We were given a problem to allow a user to enter any number of info using an EOF controlled while loop to iterate multiple entries.
While I'm able to set up the general code for this, I'm running into the issue of the last outputs of the loop still printing when I try to exit the loop using the eof function ctrl+z.
I set up the code to pre-read the data that's input by the user before entering the loop, but when I initiate ctrl + z it exits the loop but still reads to the end of the loop and prints the output asking for data:
Enter the name of the destination: (ctrl+z here to exit loop using eof)
Enter the number of miles travelled: Enter the number of gallons used: (prints the rest of output)
How do I stop the last part from being output using ctrl + z?
Any help or input is appreciated
This is how I set up my initial code:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //define variables
    double milesTravelled, gallonsUsed, mpg, total_miles, 
    avg_mpgPerTrip;
    int no_of_trips;
    string destinationName;

    //set counter and sum to 0
    no_of_trips = 0;
    total_miles = 0;

    //input phase
    cout << "Enter the name of the destination: ";
    cin >> destinationName;

    cout << "Enter the number of miles travelled: ";
    cin >> milesTravelled;

    cout << "Enter the number of gallons used: ";
    cin >> gallonsUsed;

    //process phase
    while(cin)//while loop EOF
    {
        mpg = milesTravelled / gallonsUsed;

        //update counter and sum
        total_miles += milesTravelled;
        no_of_trips ++;

        //output phase
        cout << "Travel Information: \n"
            << endl
            << "Destination: " << destinationName << endl
            << "Miles per Gallon: " << mpg << endl
            << endl;

        //loop exit exit prompt
        cout << "To exit the program, press: ctrl + Z, then Enter\n"
            << endl;

        //input next line of data
        cout << "Enter the name of the destination: ";
        cin >> destinationName;

        cout << "Enter the number of miles travelled: ";
        cin >> milesTravelled;

        cout << "Enter the number of gallons used: ";
        cin >> gallonsUsed;
        cout << endl;

    }//end while

    //output of counter and sum
    cout << endl
        << "Trip information entered:" << endl
        << endl
        << "Total number of trips taken: " << no_of_trips << 
        endl
        << "Total number of miles travelled: " << total_miles 
        << endl;

    return 0;
}


I tried using a control structure using if, else to tell the program to exit based off of the EOF ctrl + z

mpg = milesTravelled / gallonsUsed; -- What is the value of gallonsUsed when this statement is executed?

if (!(cin >> destinationName)) break;

The other thing is that your code is not a [mcve].  There are multiple syntax errors in the code you've posted.  Missing headers, misspellings of variables, missing braces, etc.

When you past the code, paste code you are actually using. Your code has so much typos that it impossible to compile it without lots of fixes (like missing ;).

You really can't do while(cin) like this.  It is the same logical mistake as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

This is how I set up my initial code: -- If that's true, then there is no way a program can be built due to the errors pointed out.  Until you post your real code, we do not have any idea what your real code actually is.  If you're waiting for someone to fill in the blanks and correct your mistakes by adding missing code, then there is a risk that the changes we make to your incomplete code will mask one or more errors that you are seeing.

I apologize, I manually transcribed the code from my laptop to my desktop and missed a line of code and some ; semicolons. I copied and pasted the code on my laptop, so the code should run correctly now.

On your platform Ctrl+Z terminates the std::cin input stream.  (It doesn't on my platform.)  But your code does not check for that after the Enter the name of the destination: prompt.  Which executes the rest of the code before checking the while condition as being good (which it isn't) before breaking out of the loop.

Thank you all for the responses so far.
John, when I try to use (cin >> gallonsUsed) in the while loop expression, it evlauates as true and initiates the loop, but only for one iteration then exits the loop and ends the program. Do I have to rest the variable in order to make this work?

The expression cin >> won't evaluate to false until after a read fails, it doesn't try to look-ahead to see if you're at EOF.

@Eljay the story behind Ctrl+Z is interesting, it amounts to backwards compatibility run amok and only applies to Windows.  See Why do text files end in Ctrl+Z? for some details, and the story goes even further back than Raymond admits.

Just wanted to thank everyone for all the input. I was able to find a work around while still using a while loop and eof.
In the loop, I put an if control structure for the new input of data. I set the if expression to if(cin >> char variable)

I set the expression to while (cin >> gallonsUsed). This allowed me to enter the loop and perform a calculation on the pre-read material before the loop. In the while loop, I put an if control structure for the new input of data. I set the if expression to if (cin >> exitPrompt), and define char exitPromt. This let me use an eof function ctrl + z. The last line of code in the if statement, I added cout << "Enter the number of gallons used: " to continue the while loop. Let me know if this is improper or if theres a better approach. For the class, it required the use of a while loop and eof.

@MarkRansom • I'm aware, it's an interesting backstory.  :-)  Came to DOS via CP/M.  (I used to work with Raymond.)

A while loop will check the loop condition at the start of every loop iteration. If you want the loop condition to be checked in the middle of the loop instead of at the start or end of the loop, then I recommend using an infinite loop with an explicit break statement instead, for example like this:
for (;;) // infinite loop ( equivalent to "while (true)" )
{
    mpg = milesTravelled / gallonsUsed;

    //update counter and sum
    total_miles += milesTravelled;
    no_of_trips ++;

    //output phase
    cout << "Travel Information: \n"
        << endl
        << "Destination: " << destinationName << endl
        << "Miles per Gallon: " << mpg << endl
        << endl;

    //loop exit exit prompt
    cout << "To exit the program, press: ctrl + Z, then Enter\n"
        << endl;

    //input next line of data
    cout << "Enter the name of the destination: ";
    cin >> destinationName;
    if ( cin.fail() )
        break;

    cout << "Enter the number of miles travelled: ";
    cin >> milesTravelled;
    if ( cin.fail() )
        break;

    cout << "Enter the number of gallons used: ";
    cin >> gallonsUsed;
    if ( cin.fail() )
        break;

    cout << endl;
}

Another issue is that you have a large amount of code duplication. Half of your code before your loop is duplicated inside the loop. You can get rid of this code duplication by reordering your code, for example like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //define variables
    double milesTravelled, gallonsUsed, mpg, total_miles, 
    avg_mpgPerTrip;
    int no_of_trips;
    string destinationName;

    //set counter and sum to 0
    no_of_trips = 0;
    total_miles = 0;

    for (;;) // infinite loop ( equivalent to "while (true)" )
    {
        //input phase

        cout << "Enter the name of the destination: ";
        cin >> destinationName;
        if ( cin.fail() )
            break;

        cout << "Enter the number of miles travelled: ";
        cin >> milesTravelled;
        if ( cin.fail() )
            break;

        cout << "Enter the number of gallons used: ";
        cin >> gallonsUsed;
        if ( cin.fail() )
            break;

        //process phase

        mpg = milesTravelled / gallonsUsed;

        //update counter and sum
        total_miles += milesTravelled;
        no_of_trips ++;

        //output phase
        cout
            << "Travel Information: \n"
            << endl
            << "Destination: " << destinationName << endl
            << "Miles per Gallon: " << mpg << endl
            << endl;

        //loop exit exit prompt
        cout
            << "To exit the program, press: ctrl + Z, then Enter\n"
            << endl;
    }

    //output of counter and sum
    cout
        << endl
        << "Trip information entered:" << endl
        << endl
        << "Total number of trips taken: " << no_of_trips << endl
        << "Total number of miles travelled: " << total_miles
        << endl;

    return 0;
}

This program has the following behavior:
Enter the name of the destination: London
Enter the number of miles travelled: 100
Enter the number of gallons used: 30
Travel Information:

Destination: London
Miles per Gallon: 3.33333

To exit the program, press: ctrl + Z, then Enter

Enter the name of the destination: Paris
Enter the number of miles travelled: 200
Enter the number of gallons used: 50
Travel Information:

Destination: Paris
Miles per Gallon: 4

To exit the program, press: ctrl + Z, then Enter

Enter the name of the destination: ^Z

Trip information entered:

Total number of trips taken: 2
Total number of miles travelled: 300


Thanks for the feedback; I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, we were required to use a while loop for this assignment using some form of 'while(!cin.eof())', otherwise I would've preferred to use an alternative method.   I'll have to digest this a little further. It seems that the answer my professor might have been looking for was the use of a pre-read following 'cin >> destinationName, milesTravelled, gallonsUsed' with a 'while(!cin.eof())' to check the inputs before entering the loop. Your example, however, does seem more intuitive from my perspective. Thank you all again.

@yangd14: If you write while ( cin >> destinationName >> milesTravelled >> gallonsUsed ), then you will not be printing the prompts for the input, e.g. "Enter the name of the destination: ".

@yangd14: In my code, you can replace for (;;) with while(!cin.eof()) and I believe it will still work. However, this additional check is redundant. Note that for the purpose of your assignment, cin.eof() is mostly equivalent to cin.fail() (they are not equivalent in the case of an input conversion failure or a stream error).

So what I did was: declared my pre-read statements and then used the last cin statement as the expression while (cin >> gallonsUsed) to enter the loop. Loop contains my calculations, sum and counter as well as an if control structure using a boolean variable for next input: if (exitPrompt) for either input of 1 or ctrl + z to exit. The end of the if structure contains a cout asking for the input of gallonsUsed for reiterating the while. I'm not sure if this is proper use, but ot works. Although it does make me question whether this is more in line with a flag controlled while then an EOF
